# What is the difference between an 8080 and an 8051?

Tags: 8080, microprocessor, 8051

What are the features of the [Intel 8051](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_MCS-51) architecture that allow it to successfully act as a microcontroller? Hypothetically can the general-purpose 8-bit architecture like [Intel 8080](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8080) do everything the 8051 can? If not, why?

For example, can the bit addressable IO ports of the 8051 be emulated by using bitmasking with the `IN` and `OUT` commands of the 8080? Or are the IO ports of the 8051 intrinsically different from the databus of an 8080? For example modern microcontrollers often have [dedicated circuitry](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/96932/internal-circuitry-of-io-ports-in-mcu) for the IO ports, did the 8051 have to do this to become a microcontroller?

Assume that the memory, UART, and timer/counter of the 8051 are made external. That is they are interfaced with as external devices as they would be in the 8080.

Comment: This question sounds terribly like taken form a text book. Almost as if someone doens't want to do his homework.

_Simple answer: A micocontroller is an integration of a microprocessor, RAM, ROM and ports into one chip. Join an 8080 with these other compnents and you'll get an 8080 based micocontroller :)_

And most important, a question that isn't anywhere RC related (just plunging in 8080 and 8051 instead of modern devices doesn'T make it), but about basic IT knowledge - so EE or SE main site might be a better target.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Not RC related - just because some old CPU/MCU names are used doesn't make such a generic school book question valid here

Comment: @Raffzahn. Not a textbook question, I'm not a student. I have read and reread the wikipedia pages, technical manuals, and pretty much anything I can get my hands on with regards to the two chips. I am new to electronics so a lot of it goes over my head. I am curious if an 8080 can do everything an 8051 can given the right external hardware and what was so revolutionary about the 8051.

Comment: For more context, a simple architecture like the 8080 is similar to what is often accomplished in homebrew CPUs. I am curious if homebrew CPUs that are simple can do tasks that microcontrollers can. So I'm looking into the history of the two, and where and why they split off.

Comment: Nonetheless it sounds exactly like your teacher made it up for you. It's simply CPU vs. MCU (MicroControlerUnit). A Microcontroller is a combination of processor, RAM, ROM and I/O in one package/Chip. It's nothing Architectural, just packageing. Much like a 6500/11 is a 6502 with RAM,ROM and IO in a package.  Similar combination are available for next to any CPU. And la but not least, 8080 and 8051 are not related in any way. Total different developments, none is split of the other.

Comment: For example, did the 8051 beef up its ports to allow them to drive external components, or are they the same electrically as the databus in an 8080. When I look at the datasheet of an Atmega microcontroller, it is clear [some trickery](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/96932/internal-circuitry-of-io-ports-in-mcu) is happening with the GPIO ports... did the 8051 have to do similar things architecture wise to become a microcontroller? Or is this an "enhancement" with regards to microcontroller design enacted by successor microcontrollers.

Comment: On top of all this they are completely different architecture see [What’s the difference between Von-Neumann and Harvard architectures?](https://www.microcontrollertips.com/whats-the-difference-between-von-neumann-and-harvard-architectures/). Their core is also non related at all (different registers/operations/iset). The `port` means very different things for each of them ... What makes a MCU an MCU is that it has all the stuf on board so it does not need any additional IC or stuff ... single chip is a whole computer (apart the first chips without EEPROM,RC/XTAL)

Comment: A cursory review of the datasheets for both chips would answer all of your questions, if not, then study how microprocessors and microcontrollers differ.

Comment: @Raffzahn Being a homework question doesn't make it off-topic... intrinsically. Perhaps we should decide that on [meta]. If it weren't homework am I correct in assuming that there's nothing (else) wrong with it?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Ofc is posting a homework question on RC per default off-topic. Asking such a question is not only cheating by making RC people do your homework, it's also bad for the poster, as he flunks out and avoides learnign what he is supposed to learn.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Further, there's much wrong beside the 'homework' part. As already pointed out in the first comment, it's a basic EE question: _What is a CPU vs. what is a microcontroler (MCU)_ Nothing specific retro an thus definitly not a valid RC question. Using names of older (and unrelated) CPUs can't make it on-topic either.

Comment: @Raffzahn I got blinded by the middle paragraph. Although, your statement about homework on SE is wrong; the default isn't to block it. How do you tell whether it's homework? See stuff like https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/105169 for discussions about it.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Well, seams like you're still dazled from the mid sentence? :)) In my first comment I did _not_ argue regarding the homwork part, I merly noted it. But true, I do think that answering homework for others is on-topic for RC. But I didn't do any remark about other SE sites, as every may handle it different. In fact, the physics meta youliked is a great example, as they even have a tag for that, and more important, seam to have a set of restrictions defined for this.  Likethat such aquestion needs tobe generic and helpful to others and not just about double checking or doing the work.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 _" How do you tell whether it's homework?"_ Did you not read the questions? Didn't you note phrases like _"What does [...] with regard to architecture that allows it to [...]? Hypothetically can t[...]? If not, why?", "Hypothetical ...", "Assume ... "_ and so on?  That's 100% like teachers write homework questions to make a student work out differences and similaritis and discuss about them. And they are universal. I've seen this language used in DE, EN, FR, RU, and I bet they are the same everywhere and in every language. to make the student do his job.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Now, excuse me for a few, I got to put this into a meta question :))

Comment: Actually the proper answer for this question would showsexplicitly the features important for the retro MCU architecture as found in 8051 and the features important for retro general-purpose CPU as found in 8080. Also a bunch of 'generalization' features of 8051 (that actually caused its long live) could be pointed out.

Comment: @lvd: Raffzahn has created a [question](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/640/10260) on the meta site.  You may find my answer there helpful.

Answer (score 9):

I'll keep this answer relevant to retrocomputing.  The remaining aspects of your question belong in Electronics.SE.

Without getting into those particulars, you ought to know that these chips are not at all related.  One is not the ancestor of the other.  They are entirely different architectures.

The 8080 was the CPU for the Altair, the first popular microcomputer, the computer on which Bill Gates wrote his first BASIC interpreter, and an extremely important milestone in computing history.  However, that particular chip is now completely obsolete, although it was a major influence on architectures still in use such as the x86 and the Z80.

The 8051 was never used as a main processor in a commercial system, but had some use in peripherals and embedded applications such as microwave ovens.  The architecture is still used today.

Comment: "The architecture is still used today" mainly to torture students :P j/k

Comment: _"The 8051 [...] had some use in peripherals and embedded application"_ Thats about the understatement of the century (pick any) 8051 (and it's carried over architecture) may as well be the most used on this planet.  Thanks, that comment made my day :)) Now, more serious, I would hesitate to call teh Altair the first comemrcial successful one, as there where several 8080 systems before, some even sold longer than the Altair. Calling it 'first widely popular' sounds more like it. Similar being an 'extreme' milestone. Last but not least, the 8080 lives on in many embeded cores thru the Z80.

Comment: @Tommylee2k: I think that depends on whether you are programming in assembler versus C.  IMHO the 8051 is the easiest platform for programming in assembler; e.g. no other architecture makes it so easy to manipulate bits or handle interrupts.  Although it has many C compilers, it was never designed for C (e.g. small stack, separate address spaces, the bit instructions have no direct equivalents in C).  So a person used to high level languages may be frustrated that they have to program the 8051 in assembler.

Comment: You don't really have to program the 8051 in assembler if you are used to high level languages. With the single-cycle 8051 redesign from about 15 years ago the instruction throughput is much higher which makes up for the architectural inefficiencies that kept C programs slow. Modern 8051s have extended on-chip RAM for the stack too.

Comment: @Raffzahn If I recall, even the ubiquitous SD card often uses a very heavily modified 8051 core as a microcontroller (though sometimes it uses ARM)!

Comment: "The 8051 was never used as a main processor in a commercial system" Isn't it the thing in the Magnavox Odyssey?

Comment: @Wilson: Nope.  Amazingly, the Odyssey had no integrated circuits -- all just discrete parts.  A few years later, several consoles using General Instruments chips appeared; however, these have *nothing* in common with an 8051, other than being a one-chip system.